# How can I "pre-authorize" my app so that Windows Defender allows network access?

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, windows-defender

## I'm *developing* an application

I'm a programmer (but not typically for Windows desktop or services). I'm writing an application. I want to distribute this application privately (not through the Windows Store).

## I want to avoid Windows Defender prompts

Currently, when someone runs my application for the first time, they're presented with this sort of thing:

> Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of this app

[image]

> Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of XXXX on all public and private networks
>
> Allow XXXX to communicate on these networks:
>
> [ ] Private networks such as my home or work network
>
> [ ] Public networks, such as those in airports and coffee shops (not recommended because these networks often have little or no security)

## Why? User Experience

This dialog is confusing. It's confusing for *me*. It's certainly confusing for the *industrial* customer who is deploying this to technicians in their environment.

I'm assuming there's a better solution than telling them that they need to hold a special training or have users watch a video or tape a big sign that says "click these check boxes and this button" by the machine.

Aside from that, it degrades trust in the application. It makes it look second-rate and inferior.

## SignTool vs Application Manifest vs ... ?

I'm happy to pay for a developer account. I'm happy to embed a manifest file. I'm happy to do what needs to be done to make this app "legit".

I just want to know *what* I need to do so that the application is recognized as an Authentic, Genuine, non-malware application and is able to listen on pre-defined (preferable) or dynamic (if necessary) TCP ports without popping up this obnoxious prompt.

## What can be done?

How do I "legitimize" my app so that it is trusted to listen on TCP ports?

I'm hoping it's either I change the way I listen on the network, or sign the app with certain options, or provide a manifest file, or provide a manifest file for privileged access and then edit a registry key *before* the app attempts to listen on TCP socket.

## Update: Notes to self (and others) (incomplete)

1. Use a Code Signing Certificate for Kernel Drivers and Verified Applications

   - [Microsoft.com - "Get a Code Signing Certificate"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate)
   - [Microsoft.com - "How to use SignTool.exe"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)
   - [Microsoft.com - "How to sign an App Package with SignTool"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/sign-app-package-using-signtool)
   - [Trusted Application a.k.a. ClickOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/trusted-application-deployment-overview?view=vs-2019)
   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y00n9alXHGs
2. Use a Windows Developer Account for the Windows App Store

   - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/store/register
   - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity ??
3. Create application manifest for elevated privileges

   - http://blog.fslogix.com/today-we-learn-about-elevation-integrity-levels-and-uiaccess
   - [rsrc to embed manifest](https://github.com/akavel/rsrc)
4. Create installer

   - [WiX Installer](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/wiki/Building-MSI-%E2%80%93-Step-by-step-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more commonly known as Windows Firewall. It may help if you search for Windows Firewall *without* the Defender qualifier.

Generally, it is bad form to manipulate the firewall: this is an area that is supposed to be controlled by the user or administrator. However, you do have several options.

The firewall prompt appears when an attempt is made to listen on a non-loopback interface and there is no existing rule (allow or deny) that matches it. This means any rule that matches on executable path (default, the one that's added if you accept the prompt), port number, or even globally.

- If you don't need to accept connections from other machines, listen on localhost only. This will not cause a firewall prompt to appear. You might currently be listening on all interfaces by default.
- If you are using WiX or a WiX-derived (e.g. [WixSharp](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/tree/master/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/FirewallException)) installer, you can use the [Firewall Extension](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/firewall/firewallexception.html) to add an exception for yourself at install time. Other installer toolkits may provide a similar option.
- You can programmatically add an exception with the [Windows Firewall API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/using-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security) (may require admin privileges).
- You can [call the netsh command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3565942) (may require admin privileges).

An install-time option is usually best, as most installer toolkits will also remove it cleanly on uninstall.

And last, but not least, if it's for a specific customer it really becomes an administration issue. So the most correct action might be to either use Group Policy to add the firewall rule across all computers, or, if Active Directory is not in use, prepare the system images to include the firewall rule by default.

Comment: FYI: It is Windows Defender Firewall in Windows 10 as of September 2017.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall

But point taken in regards to searching for older, quite relevant results. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't accepted the answer only because I haven't had time to test it yet. This looks great, thank you.

Comment: @CoolAJ86 Good point - I double-checked against your screenshot but that may have been from a different source. Updated to remove that bit.